# Add extra html to ubercart cart and checkout pages

Tags: theming, ubercart

I need to wrap ubercart cart, cart/checkout and other front-end pages in extra html, but cannot find a way to do it (some template files or way to add my extra html).

For example, mydomain/cart ubercart content is inside

```
<div id="cart-form-pane"></div>
```

, and i need to add more html before and after that div.

I could watch for ubercart in page.tpl.php with current_path(); and on occurance add that extra html, but would like to know is there any more propper way.

Update: it is Drupal 7 with Ubercart 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in following ways,
1) define a template file:- in your template.php, define a template file for checkout page

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function themename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = array();

  $items['uc_cart_checkout_form'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
'template' => 'uc-cart-checkout-form',
  'path' => $path . '/templates/',//where the tpl files are located
   ); 

   return $items;
 }
```

Then in your templates folder create a file uc-cart-checkout-form.tpl.php, here you can render your form with additional htmls

2) Override the theme

Check this instruction on Ubercart [How to Theme the Checkout pane in Ubercart 3](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/32119/how_theme_checkout_pane_ubercart_3), by following this you can include your custom html.

Similarly the above methods are applicable to cart page also

Comment: Thanks, i am doing implementation under 1), how exactly do i output form in uc-cart-checkout-form.tpl.php?

Comment: Got it! There is ready-made template here - http://pastebin.com/1nwkSx4A