# How to add form on ubercart checkout complete page?

Tags: ubercart

I have latest Ubercart 7.x-3.6 on Drupal 7.31 installation.
I want to add a form on cart/checkout/complete page. which api can I use to add a form on checkout complete page.

EDIT:

Ubercart's core cart checkout complete page contain an order submit message and created order link, right? Now I want to add a form bellowed to the contents of checkout complete page. I think its enough detail.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7) and use [hook_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) to create your form.

Then I would do as suggested in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46535/add-extra-html-to-ubercart-cart-and-checkout-pages) to add your custom form to the ubercart page you wish to edit, only instead of rendering items, call your new function.  Does that make sense?

Comment: is it work on checkout complete page?

Comment: Yes, it should.  By creating a copy of the [template file for the checkout complete page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606745/how-to-theme-ubercart-checkout-complete-page) you will be able to insert your new form by calling your new function that uses hook_form.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying.